# GitPython FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2]

Tags: python, gitpython

I'm trying to use `GitPython` with `diff` and my code is as follows:

```
from git import Repo

repo = Repo(r'D:\Projects\SCRIPTS\TestRepo')
t = repo.head.commit.tree
repo.git.diff(t)
```

Path includes the `.git` file.

But I'm getting errors as follows:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

and

```
    raise GitCommandNotFound(str(err))
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I've set the `git.exe` in the environment variables like this via the command line: 
`set GIT_PYTHON_GIT_EXECUTABLE="C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe"`
And verified that it works with;

`> git --version
git version 1.9.5.msysgit.1`

Eventually I'll use `GitPython` to have a list of the Diffs for the last 7 days (`git diff HEAD 'HEAD@{7 days ago}'`)

Can someone help me to find out what am I missing?

Thank you.